# Any way to get a URP shader to tile at a constant size, regardless of face orientation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I need a shader which I can apply to a surface, and have it tile a texture at a constant size. Think 'stretchable brick wall' I looked at this world shader hoping I could adapt. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vIh_6xtBwsI&ab_channel=JustinFoley
The problem with world UV's is they only project along the major axes. I need it to follow the rotation of the object, just not affected by scale.

[image: Texture follows rotation but is not affected by scale]

This is what I was trying:

[image: my shader]
But as you can imagine, it is still affected by scale, and appears to align with the y plane:

[image: my shader result]

Comment: Hint: Object Space coordinates (instead of UV), projected onto plane defined by fragment Normal

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I'm not a shader expert, do you know how I would access that 'fragment Normal' ?